# naming ruby on rails routes for many to one relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

I have 2 resources:
tasks and results

each task can have many results associated with it.

I would like to create a "best 10 results" route that will show for a given task what are the best 10 results for it.

I would like the _path helper to look like
`best_results_for_task_path(task_id)`
or `show_best_task_results_path(task_id)`

can it be achieved using a route like

`/tasks/:task_id/show_best_results`
or
`/results/show_best_for_task/:task_id`
or some other format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a list of results which is basically a collection route. I would prefer to go with the following approach

```
Route:      tasks/:task_id/best_results
Controller: tasks/results_controller || results/lists_controller
```

This keeps the results controller clean and allows us the extend the behaviour incase more list actions are needed in the future.